# How can I call function for matching key in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, find, key

```
def fin1():
    #some context
    pass

def fin2():
    #some context
    pass

def fin3():
    #some context
    pass

def fin4():
    #some context
    pass

test_dic = {"1": fin1, "2": fin2, "3": fin3, "4": fin4}

some_string = "123123wafds"

result_string = ""
for single_str in some_string:
    if single_str in test_dic:
        test_dic[single_str]()
    else:
        result_string += single_str
```

I thought complexity of making multiple if state is O(logN).
So I call function fit to key this way, because I thought it's complexity is O(1),
But it seems slow. And people say it`s dirty.

Is there other way to approach random function matching to the key or id of it?
Or some other way fix this better.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code except that you do not do anything with the return values of your functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think calling from a dict is slow, except a feeling? The best (maybe only) way to really know is to measure.

I ran the following script:

```py
def fin1():
    #some context
    pass

def fin2():
    #some context
    pass

def fin3():
    #some context
    pass

def fin4():
    #some context
    pass

test_dic = {"1": fin1, "2": fin2, "3": fin3, "4": fin4}

def indirect():
    some_string = "123123wafds" * 10000

    result_string = ""
    for single_str in some_string:
        if single_str in test_dic:
            test_dic[single_str]()
        else:
            result_string += single_str

def direct():
    some_string = "123123wafds" * 10000

    result_string = ""
    for single_str in some_string:
        if single_str == "1":
            fin1()
        elif single_str == "2":
            fin2()
        elif single_str == "3":
            fin3()
        elif single_str == "4":
            fin4()

        else:
            result_string += single_str

for i in range(1000):
    indirect()

for i in range(1000):
    direct()
```

I used the cProfile module to measure, like so:

```
$ python3 -m cProfile test_indirect.py 
         120002003 function calls in 33.458 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.001    0.001   33.458   33.458 test_indirect.py:1(<module>)
 40000000    1.941    0.000    1.941    0.000 test_indirect.py:1(fin1)
     1000   12.334    0.012   15.150    0.015 test_indirect.py:19(indirect)
     1000   15.360    0.015   18.307    0.018 test_indirect.py:29(direct)
 40000000    1.936    0.000    1.936    0.000 test_indirect.py:5(fin2)
 40000000    1.886    0.000    1.886    0.000 test_indirect.py:9(fin3)
        1    0.000    0.000   33.458   33.458 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

As the results show, indirect (using a dict) is faster than direct (using if/elif). So go ahead and use that.

Comment: Thank you. Than guess I can keep this going on!!

Comment: i just compared my new function use this format with old function use direct if state and they worked same(while old function is super nasty structure of O(N^2) complexity, for N of length of string). Turns out it was so broken that doesn't call the function(just save string itself) for some case, and that case was the strings i used to test. But still don't understand why link to function is 4 times expensive than if state, because of hash function of dictionary?